# Using a container function in a service

Tags: php, symfony

I start in php. I have a `DicomContainer`container that contains several functions. I would like to call these functions in my `WadoService`service.

```
class DicomContainer {

    /**
     * Get Patient's Name.
     * @return string Patient's Name.
     */
    public function getPatientsName() {
        //PatientsName
        return $this->getValueOf("DICOM", "PatientsName");
    }

}

class WadoService {
    $patientsname = getPatientName();???????

}
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `DicomContainer` should be instantiated to use its methods on the `WadoService` class:

```
class WadoService {

    public function someFunc()
    {
        $container    = new DicomContainer();
        $patientsname = $container->getPatientsName();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a functtion in your default value but you can use the __construct() method call in every class for initialisation.

Comment: Sorry. But how can do you this ?
`public function __construct($em) {  }`

Comment: But what I write betwwen braces ?